# WordPress - How do I retrieve custom post type posts from output of wp_get_archives

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am new to WordPress and learning by implementing. Today I have created a list of archives using `wp_get_archives` for a custom post type. The list comes up fine!

```
$args = array(
  'type' => 'monthly',
  'limit' => '15',
  'format' => 'html',
  'before' = '',
  'after' => '',
  'show_post_count' = true,
  'echo' => true,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => 'travelog'
);

wp_get_archives($args);
```

Now I am stuck with two things and no idea how to solve them!

**[ A ]**

**What I want to accomplish:**
I want to achieve the functionality that when somebody clicks on an item from the list it would take him to another page with posts listed for that period only.

**What is happening:**
WordPress takes me back to site's home page.

How can I tell WordPress to go to a page and display the posts for that period. Posts can be custom post types as well.

**[ B ]**

**What I want**
With a Custom Post Type passed (`'post_type' => 'travelog'`) link for each item be like `http://local.tourplanner.com/2017/03/travelog`

**What I am getting**
It is like `http://local.tourplanner.com/2017/03/?post_type=ravelog`

With `'post_type' => 'post'`, however, there is no query string added to and they look like `http://local.tourplanner.com/2017/03`

If possible I would love to achieve this without using any plugin.
Looking forward to your suggestions.